# How to apply stack() function on Pandas groupby Object

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I am trying to optimize my runtime at applying a stack() functionality.

```
Initial Dataframe 

  ID   SCORE1  SCORE2  YEAR
0 1111  3        4     2019
1 1111  NaN      3     2019
2 1111  5        4     2019
3 2222  6        7     2019
4 2222  2        NaN   2019
5 3333  NaN        9   2019
6 3333  4        NaN   2019
7 4444  NaN      NaN   2019
8 4444  5        6     2019
```

This groupby.apply() below worked.

But, It takes forever on a bigger Dataset (3 Million records = 25 mins)

```
var = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:, 1:3].stack())

Output Achieved

  ID  
 1111 0  SCORE1 3
         SCORE2 4
      1  SCORE2 3
      2  SCORE1 5
         SCORE2 4
2222  3  SCORE1 6
         SCORE2 7
      4  SCORE1 2 
3333  5  SCORE2 9
      6  SCORE1 4
4444  8  SCORE1 5
         SCORE2 6

Desired output : Same
```

How can I Optimize this performance ?

Can I use transform() ? How ? It does not have a stack() call

Appreciate all your insights at handing such scenarios

Comment: What `stack` function are you thinking of?  `numpy.stack` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with `melt` , and I do not think `grouby` is necessary here

```
df.drop('YEAR',1).melt('ID').dropna()


df.set_index('ID').drop('YEAR',1).stack()
```

Comment: I think OP wants a `ffill()` as well.